# How to write tests for an Interface in PHP

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, interface

If I'm writing an interface I usually specify the behavior the implementations should expose. For ensuring this behavior one should write tests against this interface. How do I best write and organize those tests in a way, that they can easily be used by writers of implementations to ensure their implementations meet the requirements?
Is some way of extending (writing subclasses) the interfaces tests the way to go or do I implements some design-pattern like factory?

Comment: As a PHP interface cannot contain an actual code, what are you trying to test? Practically, all you can do is ensure that specific methods are defined, and in such a way that they will accept certain arguments, perhaps using Reflection

Comment: I want to test the behavior of the implementations, but I don't want the write the same tests again and again for each implementation, since to the outer world they all should look the same since they are implementing the same interface. E.g. one could write the interface `XYZ` and according tests so everybody who wants to state “I'm implementing interface XYZ” just has to apply the tests to here implementation.

Comment: If you define the interface, and you define the methods that takes the interface as an argument, you're already there. Sadly, php interfaces does not specify the full method signature (missing return type for example) so you can never be sure about how the code can be used: `a_function(my_interface $obj) { $obj->method_defined_in_interface(); /*what's the return type here, can I used it with str_* functions as I wanted or did it return void/int/obj/....? */}`. On the other hand: if you have the implementations in the same code base: test them instead, the interface is already type hinted.

Comment: The idea is to not require to have all implementations in the same code base. Especially the correct return types could be tested by those test cases.

Comment: FWIW, I get what you're trying to do and I think it's a good question. An interface just defines what a method *should* look like, it cannot confirm that it *actually works* the way you intend it to beyond superficial method signatures. Bundling an implementation test together with an interface seems very sensible so implementers can confirm their work; especially if the method is supposed to compute something complex. Maybe you can use config files, e.g. "add your class here and we'll run tests for it".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an abstract class with some basic tests of interface contracts.

Consider following example:

```
interface FactorialComputer {
    public function compute($input);
}

class RecursiveFactorialComputer implements FactorialComputer  {
    public function compute($input) {
        if ($input < 0) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException(...);
        }

        if ($input == 0 || $input == 1) {
            return 1;
        }

        return $input * $this->compute($input - 1);
    }
}

class IterativeFactorialComputer implements FactorialComputer  {
    public function compute($input) {
        $result = 1;

        for ($i = 1; $i <= $input; $i++) {
            $result *= $i;
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

And tests for both implementations:

```
abstract class AbstractFactorialComputerTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    /**
     * @var FactorialComputer 
     */
    protected $instance;

    protected abstract function getComputerInstance();

    public function setUp() {
        $this->instance = $this->getComputerInstance;
    }

    /**
     * @expectedException InvalidArgumentException
     */
    public function testExceptionOnInvalidArgument() {
        $this->instance->compute(-1);
    }

    public function testEdgeCases()
    {
        $this->assertEquals(1, $this->instance->compute(0));
        $this->assertEquals(1, $this->instance->compute(1));
    }

    ...
}

class RecursiveFactorialComputerTest extends AbstractFactorialComputerTest
{
    protected abstract function getComputerInstance() {
        return new RecursiveFactorialComputer();
    }

    public function testComputeMethodCallsCount() {
        // get mock and test number of compute() calls
    }
}

class IterativeFactorialComputerTest extends AbstractFactorialComputerTest
{
    protected abstract function getComputerInstance() {
        return new IterativeFactorialComputer();
    }
}
```

Using this approach every programmer should be capable of creating a complete unit test for interface implementation.

Answer (score 4):

I get why people are telling you you should not need to test interfaces.
But that's not what you are asking.
You are asking for a simpler way of performing the same unit tests for multiple classes that implement a certain interface.
I do that using the [@dataProvider](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.dataProvider) annotation (PHPUnit, yes).

Let's assume you have these classes:

```
interface Shape {
    public function getNumberOfSides();
}

class Triangle implements Shape {
    private $sides = 3;
    
    public function getNumberOfSides() {
        return $this->sides;
    }
}

class Square implements Shape {
    private $sides = 4;
    
    public function getNumberOfSides() {
        return $this->sides;
    }
}
```

And you now want to test that for an instance of `Triangle` `getNumberOfSides` is defined and returns 3, while for a `Square` it returns 4.
This is how you write this test using `@dataProvider`:

```
class ShapeTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    /**
     * @dataProvider numberOfSidesDataProvider
     */
    public function testNumberOfSides(Shape $shape, $expectedSides){
        $this->assertEquals($shape->getNumberOfSides(), $expectedSides);
    }
    
    public function numberOfSidesDataProvider() {
        return array(
            array(new Square(), 5),
            array(new Triangle(), 3)
        );
    }
}
```

Running phpunit here produces the expected output:

```
There was 1 failure:

1) ShapeTest::testNumberOfSides with data set #0 (Square Object (...), 5)
Failed asserting that 5 matches expected 4.

/tests/ShapeTest.php:12

FAILURES!
Tests: 2, Assertions: 2, Failures: 1.
```

Comment: There is no need to begin the name with ````test```` for data providers. The failure is because you're asserting number of sides of square == 5, which is wrong. In your square class, you've defined it as 4

Comment: @JTheDev that is the intention of the code, to have an example of a failing test. Fixed the naming of the data provider, thanks for the input.